# How to Uninstall Oracle Client?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I needed to install Oracle Client. I installed just Client Mod before Admin Mode. Now I need to uninstall the first installation (client_1).

```
D:\app\user\product\11.2.0
- client_1
- client_2
```

There is no uninstall folder in client_1. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch Oracle Universal Installer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please use deinstall.bat command as Oracle also recommend it.

deinstall.bat -home complete path of Oracle home [-silent] [-checkonly] [-local]
[-paramfile complete path of input parameter property file] [-params name1=value name2=value . . .]
[-o complete path of directory for saving files] [-help]

You can download it from this location.

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html